# zipper: returns the sublist starting at focus position | but why when n > 0?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I found this type `zipper` and `get` functions defined like this:

```
type 'a zipper = 'a list * int
exception Empty

let empty = ([], 0)

(* get: returns the sublist starting at focus position *)
let rec get lz = 
  match lz with
  | (l, 0) -> l 
  | (h::t, n) when n > 0 -> get (t, n-1)
  | _ -> raise Empty
```

But that `when n > 0` is not clear to me, that is not necessary, because *assuming* we will provide argument `n > 0`, it will always be captured by the first match, isn't this correct? Why that `when n > 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you can't assume that the value of `n` will either be `0` or a positive value, because `int` is a signed type.

Nothing would stop you some writing:

```
get ([1;2;3;4;5;6], -1)
```

Though `Empty` is a very odd choice of names for an exception in this situation. It would make much more sense to use either `Not_found` or even better, `Invalid_argument`.

I would further add that the type alias here seems rather non-idiomatic. Rather:

```
let rec get i lst =
  match lst, i with
  | l, 0 -> l
  | h::t, n when n > 0 -> get (i-1) t
  | _ -> invalid_arg "Negative index"
```

Comment: `Empty` would refer here that the sublist after the focus position is an empty one, but I agree with `Invalid_argument`